# windows mobile application

Tags: vb.net, windows-mobile

in my application, to get the path I use the following code.

```
Dim path As String
Dim asm As [Assembly] = [Assembly].GetExecutingAssembly()
path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(asm.GetName().CodeBase)
```

this gives path as `\Application Data\`
But i need `\Program Files\` to locate the `.sdf` file. how to get this path?

Comment: assuming you're right about the title of your question, in a Mobile Environment `Progam Files` do not exist, and your database file should be in your application root path...

Answer (score 0):

If you work with windows mobile under version 7 (windows phon) check this :
C# code:

```
public static string GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder folder)
{
      //buffer to fill with path
      StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(MaxPath);

      //pass stringbuilder and folder identifier to api function
      if(!Convert.ToBoolean(SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero,
         path, (int)folder, 0)))
      {
         throw new Exception("Cannot get folder path!");
      }

      return path.ToString();
}

[DllImport("coredll", EntryPoint="SHGetSpecialFolderPath",
   SetLastError=false)]
internal static extern int SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr hwndOwner,
   StringBuilder lpszPath, int nFolder, int fCreate);
```

VB.net Code :

```
Public Shared Function GetFolderPath(folder As SpecialFolder) As String
    'buffer to fill with path
    Dim path As New StringBuilder(MaxPath)

    'pass stringbuilder and folder identifier to api function
    If Not Convert.ToBoolean(SHGetSpecialFolderPath(IntPtr.Zero, path, CInt(folder), 0)) Then
        Throw New Exception("Cannot get folder path!")
    End If

    Return path.ToString()
End Function

<DllImport("coredll", EntryPoint := "SHGetSpecialFolderPath", SetLastError := False)> _
Friend Shared Function SHGetSpecialFolderPath(hwndOwner As IntPtr, lpszPath As StringBuilder, nFolder As Integer, fCreate As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

You got to `Import System.Environment` to see special folder and 
           `Import System.Runtime.InteropServices` to see DllImport

For Details : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446567.aspx#spfiles_topic_03

Please, if It's working mark my answer as **Right**

Answer (score 0):

I normally use asm.CodeBase directly (but not with Windows Mobile). Does this works for you?